# Only show M (motoway) roads in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to only display the major roads in the UK, or M roads.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using the above options still displays all of the `A` roads, in other words too many roads:
[image]

I only want to display the M (blue) roads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will hide A highroads but show the M highroads :

```
     [{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access",
       "elementType":"all",
       "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},
      {"featureType":"road.highway",
       "elementType":"all",
       "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]}]
```

I would suggest you check out this (or any other google map style editor)
http://www.mapstylr.com/map-style-editor/

You'll be able to find everything that is customizable.

Comment: But I don't want to hide everything... I want M roads to show lol

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it does exactly what you need (show only M roads)

Comment: The editor is great, there are a few bugs that I notice, or at least undesirable UX but otherwise very nice